# Iterate through changing range in VBA

Tags: vba, iterator

I am iterating through a range in VBA, currently in a for loop. I have an if statement that removes values from the range when they meet certain criteria, however when i do this the next value in the range is skipped.

I know I can get around this with an array and an iterator in Java, does VBA have anything like this?

Comment: Are you using `For var = ...` or `For Each`?

Comment: i was using for each now using for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to iterate backwards when deleting rows therefore you have to use the `for` loop instead of `for each`

You set `i` to the last row in range and then add `step -1` to have the loop decrement the `i`

sample `for each` which **WILL NOT** work properly

```
dim cell as Range
for each cell in Range("A1:A100")
    if isEmpty(cell) then cell.delete shift:=xlUp
next
```

A replacement `For` loop that will delete rows if they are empty

```
dim i as long, lastRow as Long, firstRow as Long
lastRow = 100: firstRow = 1
dim cell as Range
for i = lastRow to firstRow step -1
    Set cell = Range("A" & i)
    if isEmpty(cell) then cell.Delete shift:=xlUp
    Set cell = Nothing
next i
```